# Media query doesn't work on specified query

Tags: javascript, html, css, media-queries

When I set my style for a certain detect type, instead of using that media style at the designated media detected width, it uses it as a parent value which I don't understand why it's doing that.

Fiddle without said style applied: http://jsfiddle.net/T6Sk4/ works normally

Fiddle with it applied to specific width: http://jsfiddle.net/T6Sk4/1/ hmm..

```
@media (min-width: 320px) {
    #contain {
        width:300px;
    }
    .box {
        display:none;
    }
}
@media (min-width: 480px) {
    #contain {
        width:460px;
    }
}
@media (min-width: 600px) {
    #contain {
        width:580px;
    }
}
@media (min-width: 760px) {
    #contain {
        width:740px;
    }
}
@media (min-width: 900px) {
    #contain {
        width:880px;
    }
}
@media (min-width: 1038px) {
    #contain {
        width:980px;
    }
}
```

Comment: Place them in a decending manner. I mean highest width in the top then less than that below that then so on. Then check if they work.

Comment: That unfortunately will not work and I know because the style will load the smallest query over it's inherit value.

Comment: No, not only the smallest query is used. ALL of them are used (if the condition is fulfilled). Media queries are no "if-then-else" construct. So changing the order will make a difference. But it's not the cleanest way...

Answer (score 1):

Ok. Change your code for `480px` with the following code. It is working fine in all the screens without the `320px` screen. I have tested. So try this and let me know:

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 480px) {
 #contain {
    width:460px;
 }
.box {
    display:block;
 }
}
```

Also you should use your code like this way `@media only screen and (min-width:480px){}` for all the screens. If don't understand check my code.

Answer (score 0):

The minimal width is greater then `320px` so each media query is applied, as each matches.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to improve performance and readability, add max-width values too. At the moment, all of your rules are used on large screens, overwriting the same rule quite often. The second benefit: you know exactly which rule applies.

Comment: Using max-width will add a ton of extra css because you'll be re-declaring every style, including those you want to use at every width.

Comment: wow... no? because styles you want to use at every width don't have to be inside a media query? why should I even do that?

Comment: In this example, if you want `.box` to display at width >= 480px, you can set `display: block` once and be done. Using max-width, you have to do it in every media-query after = 4 extra declarations just for one thing.

Comment: did you notice that you can use multiple media-queries in one document? if you want to have the display-code starting at 480px then make a query for that. but you don't have to redefine the width of an element in every selector just because of that. or redeclare everything else just because of that. but overwriting the width in every element is just not performant at all

Comment: Right, then why not just use min-width and forego the extra media-queries?

Comment: because right now you would define the width of the same element 6 times (on a large screen) and your browser has to read ALL of those declarations, even if they are overwritten later. And this is just the width of one single element. Imagine if you do that for a whole website...

Comment: I think we're talking about different things - do you mean within the element itself, like `max-width: 90%'? Because if so, I 100% agree and misunderstood your answer.

Comment: no i mean in the media query. for example: @media (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 479px) {
    #contain {
        width:300px;
    }
}

Comment: Ok, but you still have to declare the width in every media-query... @media `(min-width: 480px) and (max-width: 599px) { #contain { width:460px; } }` @media (min-width: 600px) and (max-width:760px) {#contain { width:580px; } }, etc... and you'll have additional media-queries to set `.box` to `display: box` or you'll have to declare that multiple times as well.

Comment: yes YOU have to write it (as you do have now), of course as you want to change it (i would suggest using a flexible layout with percent, but this is not the topic). but the browser doesn't have to read it if it's not important. it's just more performant. and more readable if you search for the code that fits for a specific resolution. That's what I was saying in my answer, nothing more or less. and you don't get trouble with code for the 320px-Version that is maybe loaded last just because of it's position in the document and then overwrites the one for widescreen.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42532/discussion-between-brouxhaha-and-ria-elliger)